# When a second router is connected to my internet router, Connection-specific DNS Suffix keeps changing for an incorrect one(?)

Tags: networking, router, dns

When another router is connected to my internet router by ethernet cable, after hours the Connection-specific DNS Suffix seems to change to a incorrect one (I believe it changes to the one in that second router, because it display it's "name" in Connection-specific DNS Suffix when I do /ipconfig)
Consequently the internet stops working on my computer, and then takes hours for it to get fixed somehow (by me trying a myriad of things)
Now I stopped adding the second router in the network and it never happened again.. tho I still would like to use it.
How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Only one router should be a DHCP server

Answer (score 0):

The DNS suffix is just a symptom that indicates that your computer is receiving configuration from a different DHCP server.

The actual problem is that your computer is receiving configuration from a different DHCP server – i.e. the one within your second router, which announces itself as the "default gateway" because it *thinks* it has Internet access (even though it doesn't).

If you connected the second router purely for Wi-Fi (i.e. not for routing), make sure you disable its LAN DHCP server (as well as UPnP while you're at it).

Comment: Thanks I think this is the fix. Ive just done that... however seems like second router automatically re-enabled DHCP server again and the problem repeated...